# Sitecore8 : On publish Indexing strategy

Tags: indexing, sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore8

Currently I have configured `IntervalAsynchronousStrategy` for all the three databases (master,web and core) which rebuild indexes after specified time interval but I want to change indexing strategy so that indexing should only happen after publishing rather than after every specified time interval. I tried changing the strategy by defining the below configurations in the config file for only master database:

```xml
<onPublishEndAsync type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.OnPublishEndAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
      <param desc="database">master</param>
      <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>
</onPublishEndAsync>
```

Attached this strategy with the index:

```xml
<indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
      <index id="sitecore_master_media_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration" />
    <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
          <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
        </strategies>
        <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
            <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          </policies>
        </commitPolicyExecutor>
        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>master</Database>
            <Root>{9076FDC8-33B3-4B97-AC32-640F3481C37F}</Root>
          </crawler>
        </locations>
      </index>
```

Before publishing the edited item, I deleted the index folder of "sitecore_master_media_index" from `/AppData/indexes`. Then published the item  but the index folder was not created post publish.

Am I missing any configuration ?

Comment: Has Marek's answer worked for you? If so, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

`OnPublishEndAsync` strategy works only with the databases which are targets of publishing. In most of the scenarios it's only `web` database. This strategy only works when `EventQueue` is enabled.

For your master database you should use either `syncMaster` or `intervalAsyncMaster` strategy.

For more details read [Sitecore: Index Update Strategies](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/04/sitecore-7-index-update-strategies.aspx) blog post from John West.

Comment: As you suggested, I used "OnPublishEndAsync" strategy only for web database for "Sitecore_web_media_index" and as well as for all the web indexes that i have used but  i am getting below error:
" Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/OnPublishEndAsync "

Comment: It should be defined in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultConfigurations.config` file